# Automatic password error message on php BEFORE atempting to login

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a simple php login form which connects to a database and checks the validity of username and password. If they are correct it allows access if not an error message is displayed. My problem is that when I go to my login page it is automatically giving me an error message saying"invalid user etc" before i have even attempted to login in. Any suggestions as to why this might be?

```
  <?php
        session_start();
    include('conn.php');
    $theUserID = $_POST['userID'];
    $theUserPassword = $_POST['password'];
    $query = "SELECT userID, firstName, password FROM user INNER JOIN password ON user.passwordID=password.passwordID WHERE userID='$theUserID' AND password='$theUserPassword'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){


//let them in 
    $_SESSION['myuser40058058']=$theUserID;
    Header("Location:index.php");
  }
  else{

      $message = "Incorrect Username or Password";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
  }

?>
```

Comment: *achoo* `ajax` *achoo*

Comment: @ThisGuy Gesundheit. I'd start with a little `isset` first…

Comment: Or check the request method

Comment: @mj1 This code executes when you just visit the login page, yes? Even without submitting the form, this code executes, yes? There's an `if..else` in there, one of which *will* always be executed, yes?

Comment: That's because you're querying the database already without any values at hand to validate.. hence your code goes to the else block

Comment: @mj19925 use if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // login code. }

Comment: @deceze true - but still, if you want to qry the db before anything else, use ajax (IMO) - EDIT: oh I think I just understood the question... xD

Comment: $var=(mysqli_num_rows($result));
    
    if (isset($var)) {
      
      
//let them in 
    $_SESSION['myuser40058058']=$theUserID;
    Header("Location:index.php");
  }
  else{

Comment: So something like this guys? I'm not familiar with isset

Comment: isset( variable to check) — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL see http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
```

check if the form was posted and user and password are set

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['userID']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
```

THIS IS ABSOLUTE UNSECURE !!!
  check Paths for include and test values of the form!!

```
include('conn.php');
$theUserID = $_POST['userID'];
$theUserPassword = $_POST['password'];
```

THIS IS UNSECURE !!!
  use at least a $mysqli->real_escape_string($YOUR_VARIABLES) in the query

```
$query = "SELECT userID, firstName, password FROM user INNER JOIN password ON user.passwordID=password.passwordID WHERE userID='$theUserID' AND password='$theUserPassword'";


  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    //let them in 
    $_SESSION['myuser40058058']=$theUserID;
    Header("Location:index.php");
  }else{
    $message = "Incorrect Username or Password";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I am aware of the security issues and i will be working on them in the future its only a first attempt at a web app for college